# Homeomorphism between $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$ and $\mathbb{Q}\cap(0,1)$

Tags: general-topology

I'm asked to prove that $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}\cap(0,1)$ (order topology). I know that there is a classical theorem of Sierpinski which says that every countable, metrizable space without isolated points is
homeomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$, but the proof seems to be quite long and use many non-trivial results.

There is a hint for this exercise: "use mathematical induction twice". Can I prove it by something like [back-and-forth method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-and-forth_method)? How?

Comment: Can you do it for just one endpoint, and apply that idea twice?